# how to reset settings on android studio

Tags: android-studio, settings

I have just started learning android studio on windows without ubuntu and as I was seeing its setting I changed something that I didn't knew about and now it has become very big and I can't bring it to its original size [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYv58.png)

I tried searching for solution on net but I couldn't find one Please tell me how to reset settings for android studio on windows without ubuntu